# Android Sqlite database schema

Tags: android, sqlite

I think I have created an sqllite database with android but every time I go to do an insert it claims a column does not exist. How can I view the schema and is the onCreate method called on object creation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with code. Sqlite has a table called    "sqlite_master " which holds the schema information.

```
    /**
     * Get all table Details from the sqlite_master table in Db.
     * 
     * @return An ArrayList of table details.
     */
    public ArrayList<String[]> getDbTableDetails() {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
        ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        int i = 0;
        result.add(c.getColumnNames());
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            String[] temp = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = c.getString(i);
            }
            result.add(temp);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

A more simple way is to run it on the emulator .

1. open ddms perspective
2. Find data/data/PACKAGENAME/database/YOURFILE
3. Click the pull from db button on top right shown in picture.

Open  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to try and see using the emulator. How can this be done?

Comment: In the second part, how do I read the file I get? When I open it in a text editor it looks like its a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to examine the schema of your database is to `adb shell` into the device (or emulator).  Launch sqlite's command line with: `sqlite3 <path to your database>` and type `.schema` at the command prompt.

See:  http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html

Comment: For some reason running "sqlite3" got me the message "/system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found", but I managed to find the program in a folder of root browser (which I have bought&installed) by executing "find | grep sqlite3" (after running "su" - which I can do because my phone is rooted)

Comment: I believe that sqlite3 is unavailable on device, it is only on an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can get table names as follows:

```
    /**
     * Get all table Details from the sqlite_master table in Db.
     * 
     * SQlite has a table called "sqlite_master " which holds schema information.
     * 
     * @return An ArrayList of table names.
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getDbTableNames(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                    result.add( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        return result;
    }
```